# Instalo npm y me advierte de librerías obsoletas

Tags: npm, deprecated

Cuando se me advierte de que una dependencia está obsoleta (deprecated), ¿esto pudiese provocar que mi aplicación no funcone?

Answer (score 1):

La advertencia de que una dependencia está obsoleta (deprecated) significa que esa dependencia ya no es recomendada para su uso en futuras versiones o actualizaciones del software. Aunque la dependencia aún puede funcionar en la versión actual, podría dejar de funcionar en versiones futuras.

El hecho de que una dependencia esté obsoleta no necesariamente significa que su aplicación dejará de funcionar de inmediato, pero es importante tomar en cuenta esta advertencia porque a largo plazo podría provocar errores o problemas de compatibilidad en su aplicación.

Lo recomendable es actualizar la dependencia a una versión más reciente o buscar una alternativa que no esté obsoleta para evitar problemas en el futuro. En resumen, aunque una dependencia obsoleta no va a impedir que su aplicación funcione en el corto plazo, es importante considerar actualizarla para evitar problemas de compatibilidad a largo plazo.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Por favor mira [answer]